# How to prove that for a decidable problem the problem and the compliment of the problem are semi-decidable?

Tags: undecidability, proof-techniques, semi-decidability

Given a decidable problem, how would I go about proofing that the problem and the complement of the problem have to be semi-decidable?

Comment: Isn't this a basic result whose proof can be found in any computability book?

Comment: The answer depends on the exact definitions you use, but given the definitions, should be straightforward.

Comment: Given a decider that your programs can call, could you write the other two programs that would demonstrate the semi-decidability of those two problems? How?